# Change colour on area of screen after mouseclick, and stay changed after release Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

so I have a background to my game. If an event (click) occurs, an area of the background changes colour. When I release the mouseclick, the screen updates and returns to the original colour which I don't want to happen.

The issue is clearly that the background updates after every iteration of the game loop, returning it to its original state, however, I believe I need the background to keep updating, but also for the clicks change to stay in permanent effect? So I need to find a way so that after a mouseclick, the 
clicked area changes color, while the game continues to loop.

```
class Game(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.squares = []
        self.occupied = []
    for x in range(0,8,1):
        for y in range(0,8,1):
            if (x + y) % 2 !=0:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, [x*100, y*100, 100, 100])
            elif(x + y) % 2 ==0:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, aqua, [x*100, y*100, 100, 100])
            self.squares.append([x,y])
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        mx = mx//100
        my = my//100
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, [mx*100, my*100, 100, 100])

while not game_over:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game_over = True
        game = Game()
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)
```

pygame.quit()
quit()

Comment: Please show the relevant code. You are not showing the main loop, which should be fixed to solve your issue.

Comment: Oops, forgot that, updated now.

Comment: You also should fix the indentation in the code you've shown, it's broken.

Answer (score 1):

Do not create a new instance of `Game()` each iteration. Create one instance only before the main loop, and add a method to `Game` class to update the color of the square.

Better to catch all the events in the main loop and not in the classes. When you catch an event, call the correlated class method to perform the intended action.

Below a working code:

```
import pygame

white = (255, 255, 255)
aqua = (0, 0, 100) #or whatever it really is, it's just a constant
green = (0, 255, 0)

class Game(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.squares = []
        self.occupied = []
        for x in range(0,8,1):
            for y in range(0,8,1):
                if (x + y) % 2 !=0:
                    pygame.draw.rect(screen, white, [x*100, y*100, 100, 100])
                elif(x + y) % 2 ==0:
                    pygame.draw.rect(screen, aqua, [x*100, y*100, 100, 100])
                self.squares.append([x,y])

    def colorsquare(self):
        mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        mx = mx//100
        my = my//100
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, green, [mx*100, my*100, 100, 100])

game_over = False
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
game = Game()
while not game_over:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game_over = True
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            game.colorsquare()

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30)
```

Comment: Oops, on a second look, as Mentioned in the question, both items HAD to be in the loop, and simply the mouseclick had to register every iteration of the loop over the top. Managed to sort it out eventually.